# How to increment loop variable to get next value while iterating bash arguments

Tags: bash

I need to implement the following psudo code using bash.

```
tmp_1=""
tmp_2=""
for var in "arg_list"
do
   if[var is eq to "str_1"]
   do
      var++ # shift the loop iter to next argument
      tmp_1 = var # assign the next string/argument to 'tmp_1' variable
   done
done
```

eg: if i run my bash script as follow, then the value of tmp_1 should be 'str_2'

```
<my_script>  str_1  str_2
```

I try to do this with 'shift' in bash, but it didn't work to me. how to do this implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a `for` loop. Just process `$1` every time through the loop, and use `shift` to adjust the argument list.

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    if [ "$1" = "str_1" ]
    then
        shift
        tmp_1="$1"
    fi
    shift
done
```